# GTM tag not firing even when both conditions are true

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to get a GTM tag fired when the following two rules are true:
[rules image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pjx7s.png)

The content of the custom js variable is:

```js
function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    var thankyouMessage = document.querySelector("#newsletter-success").innerHTML === "Thank you for your subscription.";
    console.log('thankyouMessage', thankyouMessage);
    return thankyouMessage;
  }, 2000)
}
```

Currently the tag is not fired.
Whenever i remove the custom rule the tag gets fired, but when I add it I can see 'true' printed to my console, which means the custom rule runs correctly.
I tried also using a different custom rule which doesn't involve 'setTimeout' and it worked. But I have to use the timeout because the event i try to catch does not happen immediately.

How can I fire the tag correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Itai. The problem here is that `thankyouMessage` is being returned to the function within `setTimeout` and not the outer function. I don't have a solution at hand for deferred custom js variables; but if I was in your position I'd consider moving this code on to your site - and pushing the content in to the GTM `dataLayer`. Is that a viable option for you?

Comment: No, I don't have access to the code. But thanks for explaining the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using a custom javascript variable you can edit the code to be a custom html Tag.

The Custom HTML Tag will be triggered by the an All Elements Click Trigger where Click Class equals button. (Your same trigger without the ThanksForSub.. check).

The Custom HTML Tag will call the timeout function but rather than return a value it will do a dataLayer.push with the result included in it.

You will then create a custom event trigger using this event and dataLayer value on the Tag you wished to originally fire.

In order to access the passed value you will need to create a User Defined Variable Data Layer type, using the 'success' as the key.

Custom HTML Tag Script.

```
<script>(function() {
try {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var thankyouMessage = false;
        var thankyouMessageObj = document.querySelector("#newsletter-success");
        if(thankyouMessageObj && typeof thankyouMessageObj.innerHTML != 'undefined') {
            thankyouMessage = thankyouMessageObj.innerHTML === "Thank you for your subscription.";
        }
        console.log('thankyouMessage', thankyouMessage);
        //return thankyouMessage;
        if(typeof window.dataLayer != 'undefined') {
            window.dataLayer.push({
               'event' : 'newsleter.submit',
               'success' :  thankyouMessage
            });
        }
  }, 2000)
} catch (e) {
}})();</script>
```